# When I run 'hexo deploy' ,there is something wrong

Tags: blogs, hexo

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/***/***.github.io.git/': Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

when I run 'hexo generate -d' ,there is a wrong message like that

Answer (score 1):

In _config.yml,I changed the remote repository address,"http" to "https",it works!

Comment: Github does not work over plain http, it dos by https (SSL secure) or git (ssh secure) channels.